# Cannot write to virtual address using iowrite()

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-registers, virtual-address-space

I am trying create a hardware driver module in linux kernel. The hardware is connecting to the CPU through UART, therefore I am trying to access the UART register directly through iowrite(). However I found that I can never write to the register address. Below is code I am using:

```
release_mem_region(UARTBASE_PA, 145);

if(request_mem_region(UARTBASE_PA, 145, "myserial") ==NULL)
    printk("iomem request refused\n");

else
    UARTBASE =(u32)  ioremap_nocache((u32) UARTBASE_PA, 145);

iowrite32((u32) 0x100,(u32) (UARTBASE+0x20));

x=ioread32(UARTBASE+0x20);

printk("%x\ \n", x);
```

Where the `printk` output always are the default value instead of the one I write to it.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, please help, any idea will be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

James

Comment: Just to be sure, is the register at `UARTBASE+0x20` RW? Also, what are you writing and what are you getting? And what is the default value of the register `UARTBASE+0x20` according to your spec?